# Problem with CS50's tideman in pset3 (did not print winner of election when some pairs are tied)

Tags: c, cs50

I'm having some problem with CS50's tideman in pset3.
Everything in check50 is correct except the very last one:

```
:( print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied.
    print_winner did not print winner of election
```

And here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
        //printf("Candidate %i: %s\n", i + 1, argv[i + 1]);
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        int j = 1;
        for (j += counter; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]] += 1;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    int k = 0;
    int l = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = l; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][l] > preferences[l][i])
            {
                pairs[k].winner = i;
                pairs[k].loser = l;
                pair_count++;
                k++;
            }
            else if (preferences[i][l] < preferences[l][i])
            {
                pairs[k].loser = i;
                pairs[k].winner = l;
                pair_count++;
                k++;
            }
            if (l < candidate_count - 1)
            {
                l++;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
//int strength [MAX];
pair temp[1];
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count - 1; j++)
    {
        //if (strength[j] < strength[j + 1])
        if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] < preferences[pairs[j + 1].winner][pairs[j + 1].loser])
        {
            temp[0] = pairs[j + 1];
            pairs[j + 1] = pairs[j];
            pairs[j] = temp[0];
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
pair first[1];
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    first[0] = pairs[0];
    locked[pairs[0].winner][pairs[0].loser] = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (pairs[i].loser == pairs[i - 1].winner)
        {
            first[0] = pairs[i];
        }
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (pairs[j].loser == first[0].winner)
        {
            locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] = false;
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO

    printf("%s\n", candidates[first[0].winner]);

    return;
}
```

As far as I know, if pairs are tied, they have the same strength? And does strength mean only the total preference on winner, or the difference between winner and loser? For example, if Charlie wins Alice 7-2, is the strength 5 or 7?

I don't quite understand what causes this error, any help please?

Comment: Just came across this thread which saved my sanity: https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/enm5t8/pset3_tideman_winner_when_some_pairs_are_tied/ Turns out you need to account for multiple sources after all!